# Using db_index with ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, indexing

I just want to be on the safe side. I have this models:

```
class Player(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=64, db_index=True)
     ...  

class Match(models.Model):
     date = models.DateField()
     playerA = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name='playerA')   # neither here db_index
     playerB = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name='playerB')   # nor here db_index
     ...
```

Is the usage of `db_index` correct? And, there is no need to add extra indexes to either `playerA` or `playerB`?

Comment: Yes, `db_index` won't case errors if that's what you mean, otherwise what is your question?

Comment: No errors I know, I rather want to know whether this is applied properly and will speed up filtering through `playerA` and `playerB` filters, or do I have to additionally set `db_index` on `playerA` and `playerB` fields in the model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django automatically creates an index for all models.ForeignKey columns. Just run "./manage.py sql appname" and you'll see the sql statements for the creation of the indexes.

Comment: Thanks. Does it mean `db_index` in Player.name from my example is not needed at all?

Comment: Exactly. db_index is only needed in a ForeignKey when you want to disable the automatic index creation, in that case you use db_index=False